# Raspberry Pi resize SD Backup - HDDRawCopy1

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been using HDDRawCopy to make backup copies of the SD cards for my Raspberry Pi's.  It works well and has saved me several times when I have accidently damaged the SD card.

However, several months ago I restored an 8GB SD card image to a 16GB SD card without realizing it.  Now, a lot of water has passed under the bridge (changes, new data, etc and several backups) and I want to go back to one of the recent backups.

Yesterday I discovered that a the more recent backup images think they need to be restored to a 16 GB card and fail if I try to restore to an 8GB card, even though I know it would fit.

Is there any way to take the current 16GB SD card and resize it to fit on an 8GB SD card?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://superuser.com/q/610819/420621

Comment: have you expanded the partition on the 16GB SD Card to use all of the space?

Comment: No, this is an image which was "upgraded" from a Raspberry Pi NOOBS wheezy version to Jessie.

Comment: As I recall the NOOBS version is already expanded?

Answer (score 0):

I never used that tool. But I used DD in linux, it actually backes up even the empty space..and that is really hard to solve from the .img.
My suggestion is that you flash the backup onto a 16 gb card, flash the vanilla os that u used on a 8gb one, and then copy the files from one to another in a file explorer (only copy the partition that windows can open, the other one/s needs to remain intact)...in raspbian it shall work..